# Index folders and files in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing

I wanted to create an index of all the files and folders that i have in an enterprise cloud so i could then do the backup of it and store the index into a txt file and after i will compare the two last backups ( the txt files ) to check which files/folders changed names.

I have tried this code, but it is limited to the times of for loops that i insert into the code and i wanted to know if i could do it in a way of been almost unlimited since i never know if someone will add folders to any sub-folder:

```
    for f in next(os.walk(path))[1]:
    folder=('{}' + ". " + f).format(a)
    print(folder,file=open(filename, "a"))
    path1=path+f
    for f in next(os.walk(path1))[2]:
        files = ("   " + f)
        print(files,file=open(filename, "a"))
    b=1
    for f in next(os.walk(path1))[1]:
        folder=(" " + '{}' + "." + '{}' + ". " + f).format(a,b)
        print(folder,file=open(filename, "a"))
        path2=path1+("\\")+f
        for f in next(os.walk(path2))[2]:
            files = ("   " + f)
            print(files,file=open(filename, "a"))
        c=1
        for f in next(os.walk(path2))[1]:
            folder=("    " + '{}' + "." + '{}' + "." + '{}' + ". " + f).format(a,b,c)
            print(folder,file=open(filename, "a"))
            path3=path2+("\\")+f
            for f in next(os.walk(path3))[2]:
                files = ("      " + f)
                print(files,file=open(filename, "a"))
            d=1
            for f in next(os.walk(path3))[1]:
                folder=("       " + '{}' + "." + '{}' + "." + '{}' + "." + '{}' + ". "  + f).format(a,b,c,d)
                print(folder,file=open(filename, "a"))
                path4=path3+("\\")+f
                for f in next(os.walk(path4))[2]:
                    files = ("         " + f)
                    print(files,file=open(filename, "a"))
                e=1
                for f in next(os.walk(path4))[1]:
                    folder=("          " + '{}' + "." + '{}' + "." + '{}' + "." + '{}' + "." + '{}' + ". "  + f).format(a,b,c,d,e)
                    print(folder,file=open(filename, "a"))
                    path5=path4+("\\")+f
                    for f in next(os.walk(path5))[2]:
                        files = ("            " + f)
                        print(files,file=open(filename, "a"))
                    g=1
                    for f in next(os.walk(path5))[1]:
                        folder=("             " + '{}' + "." + '{}' + "." + '{}' + "." + '{}' + "." + '{}' +  "." + '{}' + ". "  + f).format(a,b,c,d,e,g)
                        print(folder,file=open(filename, "a"))
                        path6=path5+("\\")+f
                        for f in next(os.walk(path6))[2]:
                            files = ("               " + f)
                            print(files,file=open(filename, "a"))
                        h=1
                        for f in next(os.walk(path6))[1]:
                            folder=("                " + '{}' + "." + '{}' + "." + '{}' + "." + '{}' + "." + '{}' +  "." + '{}' +  "." + '{}' + ". "  + f).format(a,b,c,d,e,g,h)
                            print(folder,file=open(filename, "a"))
                            path7=path6+("\\")+f
                            for f in next(os.walk(path7))[2]:
                                files = ("                  " + f)
                                print(files,file=open(filename, "a"))
                            i=1
                            for f in next(os.walk(path7))[1]:
                                folder=("                   " + '{}' + "." + '{}' + "." + '{}' + "." + '{}' + "." + '{}' +  "." + '{}' +  "." + '{}' +  "." + '{}' + ". "  + f).format(a,b,c,d,e,g,h,i)
                                print(folder,file=open(filename, "a"))
                                path8=path7+("\\")+f
                                for f in next(os.walk(path8))[2]:
                                    files = ("                     " + f)
                                    print(files,file=open(filename, "a"))
                                for f in next(os.walk(path8))[1]:
                                    folder=("                      " + '{}' + "." + '{}' + "." + '{}' + "." + '{}' + "." + '{}' +  "." + '{}' +  "." + '{}' +  "." + '{}' +  "." + '{}' + ". "  + f).format(a,b,c,d,e,g,h,i,j)
                                    print(folder,file=open(filename, "a"))
                                    path9=path8+("\\")+f
                                    for f in next(os.walk(path9))[2]:
                                        files = ("                        " + f)
                                        print(files,file=open(filename, "a"))
                                    k=1
                                    for f in next(os.walk(path9))[1]:
                                        folder=("                         " + '{}' + "." + '{}' + "." + '{}' + "." + '{}' + "." + '{}' +  "." + '{}' +  "." + '{}' +  "." + '{}' +  "." + '{}' +  "." + '{}' + ". "  + f).format(a,b,c,d,e,g,h,i,j,k)
                                        print(folder,file=open(filename, "a"))
                                        path10=path9+("\\")+f
                                        for f in next(os.walk(path10))[2]:
                                            files = ("                           " + f)
                                            print(files,file=open(filename, "a"))
                                        k=k+1
                                    j=j+1
                                i=i+1
                            h=h+1
                        g=g+1
                    e=e+1
                d=d+1
            c=c+1
        b=b+1
    a=a+1
```

Is it possible to do what i want?

At the beginning of the code i have it to ask where is the main folder of the cloud ( on windows ) because we all use the OneDrive application to have the cloud in the computer.

This is an example on how i want things to show:

```
2. Handover
 2.1. 2018
    2.1.1. 1_January
      RE  0112018 Report A (by PC).msg
      RE  0112018 Report M (by FM).msg
      RE  0112018 Report N (by RB).msg
```

---

Got another idea, what if i create an array with the values. for example:

[main_folder, subfolder, subsubfolder,...]

so in this way i would do the for loop to all the values on the main folder, to go throw all the values of the subfolder, etc...

and then associated the "1." to the first value of the array, the "1.1." to the second, etc

is this a thing simply to be done? and check if it has a subfolder and if it has to add an array value?

Answer (score 0):

There almost certainly already exists a tool to index files like you want to do.

That said, if you want to do it yourself, you probably need a [recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) like this (pseudo-code):

```
def get_files(path, indent):
    for f in children_in_path:
        # print appropriately, e.g. print('{} {}'.format(indent*' ', f)
        next_path = path+f
        get_files(next_path, indent+2)
```

Maybe you also need to keep track of headings by including them as a parameter to your function.

Comment: what should i input in the indent? because it is saying that the indent is not defined and if i insert a number it says that it should be a str and not an int

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution

```
from pathlib import Path


def iter_subtree(path, layer=0):
    """Recursively iterate over each item in path 
       and print item's name.
    """

    # make Path object from input string
    path = Path(path)

    # iter the directory
    for p in path.iterdir():

        if p.is_file():
            print('\t'*layer, p.name)

        elif p.is_dir():
            print('\t'*layer, p.name+'/')
            iter_subtree(p, layer+1)

        else:
            raise FileNotFoundError()
```